# SQL statement in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to run the following SQL statement in ACCESS 2013 VBA but am getting errors due to wrong formatting (in this case I get "Semicolon (;) missing from end of statement"). Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong in the code below please?

```
Dim dbs As dao.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO TEMP2 ([Study_Date], [Created_By], [Part_Number], 
[Upper_Tolerance], [Lower_Tolerance], [ID21_Number]) VALUES ([Study_Date], 
[Created_By], [Part_Number], [Upper_Tolerance], [Lower_Tolerance], [ID21_Number]) 
FROM RAC_DATA_ENTRY 
WHERE [RAC_CAP_VALS] = '" & Me.[RAC_CAP_VALS] & "'"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `VALUES` when you're pulling data from one table to `INSERT` into another.  Use `SELECT` instead.

This example uses just two of your fields.  Add in the others you need.

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO TEMP2 ([Study_Date], [Created_By])" & _
    " SELECT [Study_Date], [Created_By] FROM RAC_DATA_ENTRY" & _
    " WHERE [RAC_CAP_VALS] = '" & Me.[RAC_CAP_VALS].Value & "';"
Debug.Print strInsert '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
dbs.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

Notes:

1. A semicolon at the end of the statement is optional.  Access will consider the statement valid with or without it.
2. `Value` is not actually required following `Me.[RAC_CAP_VALS]`, since it's the default property.  I prefer to make it explicit.
3. `dbFailOnError` gives you better information about failed inserts.  Without it, a problem such as a primary key violation would fail silently.
4. `Debug.Print strInsert` allows you to inspect the statement you built and are asking the db engine to execute.  If there is a problem, you can copy the statement text from the Immediate window and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.

Comment: Hi and thanks for that but I get a data type mismatch when running the code, in the immediate window I can see that the contents of the fields are correct but then get that error (3464). Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Is the datatype of your `RAC_DATA_ENTRY.RAC_CAP_VALS` field numeric instead of text?  If so, discard the single quotes before and after `Me.[RAC_CAP_VALS].Value` like this: `" WHERE [RAC_CAP_VALS] = " & Me.[RAC_CAP_VALS].Value & ";"`

Comment: Great, that worked, thanks - just got to iron out the myriad of other hiccups now!!

Comment: @RACdB if it works, mark the answer as CORRECT (click the checkmark).